# javascript - Check if parent methods are used inside child methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing some JS that extends a parent class and I wanted to know if there's a way to tell if a child class is using a parent method without having called it yet. Ideally I'd like to run a check in the constructor of the parent to see if any of the child methods are using the parent's methods in the method definition.

I've done a bit of research and have come across things like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` but I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction.

For instance:

```
class Path {

    constructor (name) {
        // how can I check if addRelationship have been used? If possible.
        this.relationships         = {};
        this.currentRelationship   = '';
        this.path                  = path;
    }

    addRelationship (relationship) {
        // do something
        this.currentRelationship = relationship.path;

        return this;
    }

    makePath () {
        let path = [this.path];

        if(this.currentRelationship) {
            path.push(this.currentRelationship)
        }

        return path.join("/");
    }

}

class OnePath extends Path {
    // ...
    someMethodFromThatRelationship () { }
}

class TwoPath extends Path {
    // ...
}

var onePath = new OnePath('one');
var twoPath = new TwoPath('two-path');

class SomeOtherPath extends Path {

    one () {
        return this.addRelationship(onePath);
    }

    two () {
        return this.addRelationship(twoPath);
    }

}
```

The idea of the above example is I could check if `addRelationship` is referenced in any methods and if so, register a `this.relationships.one` and `this.relationships.two` before `one()` and `two()` are actually called. I hope I'm making sense. I'd love to know if this is even possible.

**Updated**

The end result of the above code would be the ability to do the following:

```
let someOtherPath = new SomeOtherPath('some-other-path');

// now I can call
someOtherPath.relationships.one.someMethodFromThatRelationship();

// and can also call the save method from the extended class
someOtherPath.one().makePath();
// some-other-path/one

// I can also just call 
someOtherPath.makePath();
// some-other-path
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an interface?

Comment: @KeithHolliday Utlimately, yes. Or at least some form of an interface.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? And do you just need to get the names of the methods of the child class, or actually only those that call `addRelationship`?

Comment: @Bergi I need to get `only those that call addRelationship`

Comment: Poor example then :-) However, why do you need those names in the constructor already instead of at the time when `addRelationship` is called? What are you going to do with the method names? How is `.relationships` used? Please post your full, actual code.

Comment: @Bergi see updated code.

Comment: I'm not seeing the connection between `addRelationship` and `relationships.one` or `one()`. Seems like, if you want that kind of functionality, add it to the `addRelationship` function. Change it so it takes a "name" parameter or something and does `this.relationships[name] = relationship` and `this[name] = (function (nm) { return function ()  { return this.relationships[nm]; } })(name);`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree with you. I think that's a better approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to tell if a child class is using a parent method without having called it yet?

No. Figuring out what programs do without calling them is equivalent to the unsolvable [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are actually looking for is a more declarative approach for creating the relationship and its accompanying method in one go. Don't use too much magic (which a parent constructor inspecting its child class code would certainly be) but be explicit.

```
class Path {
    constructor (path) {
        this.relationships         = {};
        this.currentRelationship   = '';
        this.path                  = path;
    }
    addRelationship (name, relationship) {
        this.relationships[name] = relationship;
        this[name] = function() {
            // do something
            this.currentRelationship = name;
            return this.relationships[name];
        }
        return this;
    }

    makePath () {
        let path = this.path;
        if (this.currentRelationship) {
            path += "/" + this.relationships[this.currentRelationship].makePath();
        }
        return path;
    }
}

class SomeOtherPath extends Path {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
        this.addRelationship("one", new OnePath('one'));
        this.addRelationship("two", new TwoPath('two-path'));
    }
}
```

or even

```
class Path {
    constructor (path, relationships = {}) {
        this.relationships         = relationships;
        this.currentRelationship   = '';
        this.path                  = path;

        for (let const r in relationships)
            this.addRelationship(r, relationships[r]);
    }
    …
}

class SomeOtherPath extends Path {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name, {
           one: new OnePath('one'),
           two: new TwoPath('two-path')
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe you don't even need these child classes any more if they don't have other methods or are only instantiated once (as singletons).

Notice that the above approach will create new methods and new subpaths on every instantiation of the constructor, if you don't want that you can of course also put the declaration on the class statically. Just make `addRelationShip` a static method that initialises the default `relationships` objects and puts the methods on the class' `.prototype`. The variations of the pattern are endless.

You even might want to experiment with the proposed [decorators feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) for classes.